# Why is embedded contact homology so powerful?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology

The [Embedded Contact Homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5789) (ECH), introduced by M. Hutchings, is an invariant of (contact) three-manifolds. Since its introduction, well-known conjectures in symplectic/contact topology in dimension $3$, including the [Weinstein conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611007) and its [gen](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4839) [erali](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02262) [zations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01448), the [Arnold chord conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4319), are proved based on this invariant. Furthermore, the [ECH capacities](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2260) are used to establish a [Weyl law](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2167), which is the foundation of the [equidistribution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01869) result for generic contact forms. There are also nice applications of ECH to symplectic embedding problems in dimension $4$.

The question is: why is ECH so powerful?

To illustrate the question, the [Symplectic Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010059) (SFT) should capture more information from pseudo-holomorphic curves than ECH but the above results were not (yet) proved using SFT. One quick answer to this question would be the celebrated [ECH=SWF](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3985) theorem, which allows one to use powerful results/computations from monopole Floer homology. But eventually, one might hope to stay in the world of pseudo-holomorphic curves without appealing to gauge-theoretic invariants, in order to go to higher dimensions. So the question might be phrased as:

Is ECH a low-dimensional miracle? If not, what lessons should we learn from the selections of pseudo-holomorphic curves which define ECH?

Answer (score 12):

Without elaborating much there are three key points, with the first two laying the bedrock for the third:

1. ECH counts J-curves without caring about most information of the actual branched covers of such curves. Relatedly and more to the point, ECH counts J-curves with *certain ECH index*, and this picks out "the right" curves (separating itself from SFT).
2. In dimension 4 (where the J-curves live) we have the adjunction formula.
3. A lot of results deal with *nontriviality* of ECH, which comes from *nontriviality* of monopole Floer homology. (Ex: nontriviality of monopole Floer is what Taubes used to get existence of Reeb orbits, i.e. proof of Weinstein conjecture.) This is for the same reason that the Seiberg-Witten invariants are so powerful, because Taubes' SW = Gr result gives nontriviality results about symplectic 4-manifolds. (ECH is the "categorification" of the Gromov invariants.)

Here is another crucial point disguised as an application: On a symplectic 4-manifold with (negative) contact 3-manifold boundary, the standard "ECH curve count" yields a relative invariant in the $ECH_*$ of the boundary, while the standard "SFT curve count" yields a relative invariant in the (ordinary) contact homology $CH_*$ of the boundary. But if the contact structure is *overtwisted* then $CH_*$ is necessarily trivial, whereas $ECH_*$ can easily be nontrivial.

Comment: I am not familiar with ECH. So please excuse me if this doesn't make any sense. Can we use ECH to understand the topology a symplectic cap of a contact 3-manifold. Notice that various obstructions such as adjuction inequlaity are valid for the case of symplectic fillings of contact 3-manifolds. And although symlectic filling doesn't always exist, a symplectic cap does exist.